# Can't send ActiveCell value to an external program

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, py2exe

I made an executable based on a Python Script that I made from a Selenium Code where I put a number and then it returns a *.pdf file. Now I'm trying to create a VBA Macro in Excel to send the ActiveCell value through the Shell Command to my application:

```
Sub do_it()
    Dim RetVal As Variant
    RetVal = Shell("C:\Users\ghost\Desktop\assist_exe\dist\assist_inputc.exe " & ActiveCell.Value, 1)
End Sub
```

The `assist_inputc.exe` opens up but the ActiveCell's value is not being captured.

Comment: 1) does it work from a commandline, e.g. `assist_inputc.exe XXX` ... 2) try removing the exe suffix ... 3) replace your exe by the `echo` command to see how your argument is formatted ... 4) try enclosing the program name in single quotes (inside the double) to protect against blanks in Dir names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching related post´s i find a solution that help me in this problem :

```
Dim RetVal As Variant
RetVal = Shell("cmd /k C:\Users\ghost\Desktop\temp\dist\assist_empty.exe ", 1)
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
SendKeys ActiveCell.Value
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

I hope it works for someone with the same or similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this:

```
RetVal = Shell("cmd /k C:\Users\ghost\Desktop\assist_exe\dist\assist_inputc.exe ECHO " & ActiveCell.Value, 1)
```

and still can´t post the value from the ActiveCell into my aplication, but, if i execute the same code without the aplication path it works fine, maybe there´s a diferent way to paste the value?